# Android App monitor

Tags: android, security, monitor

I would like to create an app to monitor the communication between applications on my android. for example app A access my contacts 10 times; my app should be able to give me that info. 
any idea what I should use? the permissions? what android class will be good to look into ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Derrick. You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for guidence in asking good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, what you want is not possible in general, for bindlingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

In the specific case of wanting to monitor other apps' use of `ContactsContract`, you are welcome to download the Android source code, modify it to leak this information by one means or another (e.g., log it), and create a ROM mod from your revised version of Android. Installing that ROM mod on your device would then allow you monitor those communications. Outside of this, the most that you can do is set up a `ContentObserver` to see if apps change contact data, but you will not know what apps make those changes, let alone general read access to contacts.

Other aspects of Android app functionality might be monitorable on rooted devices without a custom ROM mod, and there is the occasional thing that can be monitored even without root.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. so how does android antivirus work? don't you think we can do it the same way?

Comment: @Derrick: "so how does android antivirus work?" -- you would have to ask the author of such an app. Most classic antivirus tools are scanners of executables, not monitors of activity.